# Ruby on rails controller create new params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In create method in controller i have:

```
def create
      @monitoring_group = MonitoringGroup.new(monitoring_group_params)
        if @monitoring_group.save
          payload = {
              value: @monitoring_groups,
              status: 201
          }
          render json: @monitoring_group, status: :created#, location: @monitoring_group
        else
          payload = {
              error: "One or more monitorings do not belong to this account",
              status: 400
          }
          render :json => payload, :status => :bad_request
        end
    end
```

And

```
 def monitoring_group_params
   params.require(:monitoring_groups).permit(:name, monitoring: [])
 end
```

I have the answer when i run the create

```
> #<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: monitoring_groups>
```

What i do to this create ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. The snippets feature is for runnable HTML/CSS/JS frontend examples that are runnable in the browser. For any other code use for spaces of indentation or fenced code blocks (```).

Answer (score 0):

What does the request look like?

The action expects an object like so:

```
{
  "monitoring_groups": {
    "name":"Some name",
    "monitoring":[]
  }
}
```

Are you adding the outer monitoring_groups key?

Also look at the development.log -> it will log the incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

You have `params.require(:monitoring_groups)`. This means that the params object expects data nested under the `:monitoring_groups` key.

If the request is coming from an HTML form, you should have something like this there:

```rb
form_for MonitoringGroup.new do |form|
  ...
end
```

Comment: That would still give `:monitoring_group` not groups.